# Java goes OutOfMemory even with enough RAM

Tags: java, windows

I have an app that uses the following jvm options:

```
-Xmx512m -Xms256m -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC 
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=2 -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=1G
```

I run it on Windows 7 x64 with 8gb RAM. And when the task manager says that there's 60% of RAM is in use, it becomes impossible to run my program, Java says "Out of memory". Even though in theory I still have almost 3gb of free RAM left. Below are screenshots of profiling my project in NetBeans (until it suddenly crashes on a random spot). What could cause these problems? Is my program really so expensive?

[image: скриншот]
<sub>(source: [SSmaker.ru](http://SSmaker.ru/68b30a7f.png))</sub>

[image: скриншот]
<sub>(source: [SSmaker.ru](http://SSmaker.ru/dc9f4410.png))</sub>

Comment: Out of memory what? There is not only the heap which can trigger that, there is also the permgen (removed in Java 8 I believe) and a lack of address space --> please include the full stack trace

Comment: What JVM are you running? Additionally, the JVM imposes memory limits on its programs that aren't directly related to the amount of either physical or virtual memory in the OS.

Comment: Why do you think you have enough memory? Xmx512m and byte[] usage are roughly the same

Comment: Why do you have so many bytes in byte arrays?

Comment: (What are the units for "Bytes Allocated", BTW?  Clearly not unit bytes.  Kbytes?)

Comment: What would they be in KBytes if it is just a letter B, so it is 512 KB, not MB.

Answer (score 0):

You should greedy-allocate your minimum required overhead.  That is,
use something like -Xms1g -XMx1g, so when your app actually starts running,
it has already reserved its maximal heap usage.